# ASP.NET MVC Entity Framework DB access in Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to access the DB I created to display a list. I am doing this in my controller. It is red underlining the db part. It is saying "The name db does not exist in the current context." Am I missing some thing to connect to the db in my code?

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Helpers;
using MIS424Assignments.Models;

namespace MIS424Assignments.Controllers
{
    [Authorize (Users="admin@wwu.edu")]
    public class RetailController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Retail
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {             
                string sql = "Select * from Product order by newid()";
                List<Product> productList = db.Product.SqlQuery(sql).ToList();
                return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the errors you are receiving?

Comment: You will have to execute the query under your DBContext. Learn more about Entity framework here http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/add-entity-using-dbcontext.aspx

Comment: You have not initialized db. Please initialize your database to db and try. Post your result so that we can answer you better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
[Authorize (Users="admin@wwu.edu")]
public class RetailController : Controller
{

     private readonly RetailStoreEntities1 db;
    public RetailController()
    {
        db = new RetailStoreEntities1();
    }

    // GET: Retail
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {             
            string sql = "Select * from Product order by newid()";
            List<Product> productList = db.Product.SqlQuery(sql).ToList();
            return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the connection string. Could that be the problem?
If you are using EF, did you configured the connection string in your webconfig.

I used to get burned on that one when I first started with EF :-D

***UPDATE ****
The code below would go within your Context Class as the constructing sub.

Let me know if it helps

public YourContextClass() : base("RetailStoreEntities1")
    {

```
}
```

Comment: I have     <add name="RetailStoreEntities1" connectionString="metadata=res://*/RetailStoreModel.csdl|res://*/RetailStoreModel.ssdl|res://*/RetailStoreModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\RetailStore.mdf;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /> in my web config

Comment: Are you passing the ConnectionString name "RetailStoreEntities1" to your DB Context?

Comment: I will append a sample to my original post ;-)

Comment: @BasicIsaac answer is in a nutshell :-)

Answer (score 0):

Somebody here is bound to suggest to do all your DB Access from a repository, and invoke the repository methods from your controller. 
However, to quickly answer your question. 
Your project should include a class with your context

```
public class MyContext: DbContext
{
public MyContext()
     : base("myconnstringinwebconfig")
{}
//more stuff here, maybe your entities.    
}
```

and somewhere near the top of your controller, there should be a line that will initialize your context:

```
private MyContext db = new MyContext();
```

and that will fix your error message.